# HyperDB failover Delay

Tags: plugins, database, mysql, hyperdb

We are testing out hyperDB as a solution for automated DB failover for wordpress.

The environment in question consists of 2 Backend DBs. One is setup to Local Master whilst the other remote master.

We tried to delay automatic failover by 1 minute however have not acomplished this so far; i.e if DB 1 goes down, wordpress keeps trying to connect to DB1 for 1 minute before failing over to DB2.

Can anyone help with this please ?

**Updated**
This is in a lab environment so it consists of 3 VMs (1 Front end and 2 hosting MYSQL DBs)
Environment specifications

- webserver: IIS
- PHP Version: 5.6
- Wordpress version: 4.6.1
- MYSQL: 5.7.1.6

Comment: do you think you provided enough info for others to understand your problem?

Comment: @prosti Updated post

Comment: Are you using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/hyperdb/ ?

Comment: @prosti. Yes I am that is hyperDB. Automatic failover works, It's the delayed failover which we are unable to get to work.